# background on item click listener android

Tags: android

I have a `Gridview` where i have many images that I get from `url`. I have added all of them to an `Arraylist` and set the `Arraylist` to `Gridview`. I have used

```
 grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                                           //my code here

                                     }
```

so, now when i click on `GridView` items i get a border around each grid item. can I change the color of border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In the layout of the grid items you can set the background drawable as a Selector. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList  You can set each state of the item (pressed, focused, default, etc.) to correspond to any color (or drawable) you want. It would be easiest for you to make the border as a custom drawable. Either a Shape or a 9-patch.

Comment: You can make your drawable look any way you want. With a border, without a border, solid color, transparent, gradient, bitmap, anything goes. Selectors basically swap the resource out with whatever you point the state to. And it's all done in XML.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

look at this example

res/drawable/border.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/green"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

res/drawable/grid_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/border" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> 
</selector>
```

now use in gridview is property  `android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_item_selector"`

in main.xml

```
        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                     android:columnWidth="90dp"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                         android:gravity="center" 
                    android:horizontalSpacing="-1px"
                        android:verticalSpacing="-1px"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_item_selector"/>
```